# Some Chinese characters cannot be interpreted when REST call is triggered

Tags: java

Hopefully there are some of you who already encountered this problem and had a fix for it.

I've been encountering a problem with some Chinese characters like ('','') because when the REST call is triggered, they are transformed as 'ࠀª' and our Backend system cannot interpret this.

I've created a simple springboot program to check. see below. The character encoding is set to UTF-8

```
@RequestMapping(value="/chinese", method= RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json", consumes="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public String interpret(@RequestBody SampleRESTBean bean ) {

    String value = bean.getChineseName();

    return value;
}
```

The bean object below

```
public class SampleRESTBean {

private String chineseName;

public String getChineseName() {
    return chineseName;
}

public void setChineseName(String chineseName) {
    this.chineseName = chineseName;
}
```

Now, to test (in Postman), My JSON object is set as below

```
{"chineseName":"獲保意外,另危疾加1/1000" }
```

When the object is inside the method, it looks like this
਍­獲ࠀª保意外,另危疾加1/1000

The other Chinese characters are interpreted but some specific characters are not.

Is there a solution for this kind of problem? I've searched for many references but still, I cannot fix this issue. Also, if your have a solution as well when JAX-RS is used because it produces the same issue.

Need your assistance please. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of research shows that:

- The unicode codepoint for  is u+2836D
- The unicode codepoint for  is u+2002A

Both are codepoints in code plane 2.

I suspect that the problem is in the way that your client-side or server-side software stack is handling characters that are not in Unicode code-plane 0 (aka the BMP).  These are represented as 2 `char` values when the data is converted to an array of `char` (or a `String`, `StringBuffer`, etcetera.)  Some (old) libraries and a lot of custom code don't handle this properly.

I suggest that you do the following:

1. Brush up on your understanding of Unicode, UTF-16, UTF-8 and "surrogate pairs".
2. Brush up on your skills in using a Java debugger.
3. Use the debugger to find out what is happening on the client and server-side<sup>1</sup>.
4. Once you have found what is causing the problem:

   - If it is your code, fix it.
   - If it is someone else's code, submit a bug report and/or look for a newer version that has already fixed the problem.

---

<sup>1 - Set breakpoints at key points and look at the `char` values in the data structures that are passing the data around.  Look for where the values seem to go "bad".</sup>